# Validator class in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

In my controller I validate fields of my json request. To obey single responsibility, I want to create a custom Validator class and put following code to my validator class.

When I type:

```
php artisan make:validator MyValidator
```

I found out that validator class doesn't exist in newer versions. So where should I put following code in Laravel 10? Keeping in controller doesn't seem a best practice.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->json()->all(), [
    "field1" => "required",
    "field2" => "required|numeric",
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json([
       'message' => __("Please fill required fields"),
       'errors' => $validator->errors(),
    ], 422);
}
```

Comment: Something like https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: You can create FormRequest Validation classes to validate your request. Have a detailed look at [https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use this command 
`php artisan make:request StorePostRequest`

and put your validation conditions in the `rules` function

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

also you need to change the return of the another function in that file which is named `authorize`: (because we usually check the permission on the router file we directly return true)

```php
public function authorize(): bool
{
    /* if you haven't checked the authorization, you can return Auth::user(); */
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of laravel you can follow these steps.
Run the command

```
php artisan make:request ProjectStoreRequest
```

and put your validation conditions in the rules function

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
     "field1" => "required",
    "field2" => "required|numeric"
    ];
}
```

Ensure the authorize method returns true

```
public function authorize(): bool
{
    /* if you haven't checked the authorization, you can return return Auth::user(); */
    return true;
}
```

Then in your store method you can have the

```
use App\Http\Requests\ProjectStoreRequest;

public function store(ProjectStoreRequest $request)
{
    // Validation passed, you can access validated data using $request
    $data = $request->validated();

    // Create or store the data in your database
    // ...

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Data stored successfully'], 200);
}
```